# Regex - Match pattern containing at least non space character

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like this:

```
Select a, CASE 
WHEN 1 
THEN 
   CASE some text
     WHEN 2 THEN A 
   END 
END
```

I want to replace each `'CASE (any non space) WHEN'` by `'CASE var WHEN'`
`'CASE WHEN'` (with only spaces between 2 words), should not be affected.

for the previous example, it should give this:

```
Select a, CASE 
WHEN 1 
THEN 
  CASE var
  WHEN 2 THEN A 
  END 
END
```

Tried this:

```
string.replaceAll("CASE\\s*(.*\\S.*?)\\s*WHEN", "CASE var WHEN")
```

It works in most cases but fails when 'CASE WHEN' (with spaces between) is followed by another CASE WHEN. It replaces all between first CASE and last WHEN with var, which is not what I want.

For previous example it gives:

```
Select a, CASE 
var
  WHEN 2 THEN A 
  END 
END
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
String reg = "(?i)(\\bcase\\s+)\\S((?!\\bCASE\\s).)*?(?=\\s+when\\b)";
String repl = str.replaceAll(reg, "$1var");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIQ7Tw/2/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?i)`: Enable ignore case mode
- `(\bcase\s+)`: Match word `case` followed by a whitespace
- `\S`: Match a non-whitespace
- `((?!\bCASE\\s).)*?`: Match 0 or more characters as long as it doesn't contain `CASE`
- `(?=\s+when\\b)`: Lookahead to assert that we have 1+ whitespaces followed by `when` ahead

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/fLE10L)